# Java home path error while configuring hadoop in windows 7

Tags: java, hadoop

I am working on hadoop. I was looking for hadoop installation on Windows though everywhere it is mentioned to be installed on linux/unix system. While configuring hadoop on windows, the problem I am facing is Java home path. As there is only jre installed on my machine, I mentioned the same path in environment variable and in hadoop-env.cmd file. When I am trying to use any hadoop command it is giving me error saying Java home not correctly specified.
Here is my Java home path
"C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin"
There is not jdk installed in there.

Please help me installing hadoop with the same configuration I have.

Note: As the machines are provided by my organisation, I don't have rights to installed java related software. By default we have that jre installed in our machines by our administrator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hadoop requires a JDK, so you need a JDK 6+ installed.